# How to render text in Directwrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to render text into DirectWrite????](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166709/is-there-any-way-to-render-text-into-directwrite)

Hello, all is it possible to render text in Directwrite and save it as png image using ASP.NET C# for my web application. IF YES please HELP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you its That what you mean but try this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.DrawString("HALLO", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, 10));
bitmap.Save(<Put Filestream here>);
```

Comment: This is, quite obviously, *not* DirectWrite.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know more about DirectWrite but if you have got the string value you need to render you can render it easy

```
void fun()
{
    int width = 220, height = 115;
    int xPosition=5,yPosition=5;
    Image m = new Bitmap(width,height);
    Graphics gx = Graphics.FromImage(m);
    gx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    gx.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    gx.DrawString("Hello Wrold", new System.Drawing.Font("tahoma", 12.0f), Brushes.Black, xPosition, yPosition);
    m.Save(@"d:\myimage.png",ImageFormat.Png);
}
```